# Matching and Merging csv data fields based on a common field

Tags: php

I need to read 2 csv file data, merge the headers and remove the duplicated headers. Then I need to add the data to the corresponding header, if the file has no data for the header, default it to empty.

```
For example:

File one:
'Name', 'Surname', 'Address'
'John', 'Doe',     'example st 123'

File two:
'Surname', 'City', 'Gender'
'Doe',     'Riga',  'Male'

Output File:
'Name', 'Surname', 'Address', 'City', 'Gender'
'John', 'Doe','example st 123', ' ',   ' '
' ',    'Doe',        ' ',    'Riga', 'Male'
```

For now I have made a class giving me these arrays:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Name"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Surname"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Address"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "City"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "Gender"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "John"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "Doe"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "Street 123"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "Doe"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "Riga"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "Male"
    }
  }
}
```

This is done with this class:

```
class Reader
{
    private $filePaths = [];
    private $headers = [];
    private $data = [];

    public function add(string $filePath): void
    {
        $this->filePaths[] = $filePath;
    }
    public function read(): void
    {
        foreach ($this->filePaths as $filePath) {

            $getData = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filePath));

            $this->headers = array_unique(array_merge($this->headers, $getData[0]));

            unset($getData[0]);

            $this->data[] = $getData;
        }
    }

    public function getData(): array
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function getHeaders(): array
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }
```

Could anyone please help me understand how to format the data to get the expected outcome?

For now all I can get is this:

```
Name,Surname,Address,City,Gender
John,Doe,"Street 123"
Doe,Riga,Male
```

Comment: I would approach this by processing the headers first and build a map. Then process the data and apply the map. In your approach, you handle the header and data all at once so when you process file 2, the data for file 1 was already processed.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to go about doing this? For example how to build a map? I'm very new to this kind of thing.. :D I could not merge the headers as well if you have an idea how to go form there.

Comment: Also note that this sort of approach can never handle very large data sets because it stores all the data in memory. This is fine for learning or doing small sets of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
class Reader
{
    public $filePaths = [];
    private $headers = [];
    private $data = [];

    private $originalHeaders = [

    ];

    public function add(string $filePath): void
    {
        $this->filePaths[] = $filePath;
    }
    public function read(): void
    {
        foreach ($this->filePaths as $filePath) {
            $fp = fopen($filePath, 'r');

            $h = fgetcsv($fp);
            $this->originalHeaders[] = $h;
            fclose($fp);
            $this->headers = array_unique(array_merge($this->headers, $h));
        }
        print_r($this->originalHeaders);
        print_r($this->headers);


        $i = 0; // so we know which file we are processing
        foreach ($this->filePaths as $i => $filePath) {
            $getData = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filePath));
            unset($getData[0]);

            $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $this->mapData($i, $getData));
        }
        print_r($this->data);
    }
    public function output($filename)
    {
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
        fputcsv($fp, $this->headers);
        foreach ($this->data as $row) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }


    /**
     * Map data in column i to column j
     */
    private function mapData($n, $data) : array
    {
        $inputColumns = $this->originalHeaders[$n];
        $outputColumns = $this->headers;
        $columnIndex = array_flip($outputColumns);
        $mappedData = [];
        foreach( $data as $i => $row ) {
            $workData = array_fill(0, count($this->headers), '');
            // Now take each input data and put it in the right place
            foreach ($row as $j => $value) {
                // Get name of source column
                $sourceColumn = $inputColumns[$j];
                // Where does that data go in the output
                $targetColumnIndex = $columnIndex[$sourceColumn];
                // Put the data there
                $workData[$targetColumnIndex] = $value;
            }
            // Store it in the mapped data
            $mappedData[] = $workData;
        }
        return $mappedData;
    }

    public function getData(): array
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function getHeaders(): array
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }
}

$r = new Reader();
$r->filePaths = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv'];
$r->read();
```

Input 1

```
Name,Surname,Address
John,Doe,"example st 123"
Natalie,Portman,"1 Starway Ave"
Scotty,Clarke,"Some street Mississippi"
```

Input 2

```
Surname,City,Gender
Doe,Riga,Male
Ford,"Los Angeles",Male
```

Output

```
Name,Surname,Address,City,Gender
John,Doe,"example st 123",,
Natalie,Portman,"1 Starway Ave",,
Scotty,Clarke,"Some street Mississippi",,
,Doe,,,Riga,Male
,Ford,,,"Los Angeles",Male
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Only one question tho: When I print_r the data[], the first one returns the correct amount of rows, however, the second array of data, returns one empty extra field. Is this a bug or intended?

Comment: Probably a bug.